# proving or providing counter example in disrete mathematics

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove or find a counterexample: The product of any three consecutive
natural numbers is divisible by 6.

if we take a few consecutive natural numbers such as 1 ,2 ,3. and multiply i get 6 which is obviously divisible by 6. so i know the above question is true. can anyone tell me how to prove using algebraically.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$p = n(n+1)(n+2)$$
And at least one of $n, n+1$ must be divisible by $2$, and at least one of $n,n+1,n+2$ must be divisible by $3$. Thus the product must also be divisble by $2\cdot 3=6$.

---

For a more direct proof let $n = 6k+j$ with $j\in\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ and make a case for each:
$$\begin{align*}
j = 0: p & = 6k(6k+1)(6k+2) & \checkmark \\
j = 2: p & = (6k+1)(6k+2)(6k+3) \\
& =(6k+1)2(3k+1)3(2k+1) \\
& = 6(6k+1)(3k+1)(2k+1) & \checkmark \\
j = 3: p & = (6k+3)(6k+4)(6k+5) \\
& = 3(2k+1)2(3k+2)(6k+5) \\
& = 6(2k+1)(3k+2)(6k+5) & \checkmark \\
j = 4: p & = (6k+4)(6k+5)(6k+6) \\
& = 6(k+1)(6k+4)(6k+5) & \checkmark \\
j = 5: p & = (6k+5)(6k+6)(6k+7) \\
& = 6(k+1)(6k+5)(6k+7) & \checkmark
\end{align*}$$

Comment: please refrain from giving complete and detailed solutions to homework problems.

Answer (score 0):

For each $n\in\Bbb N$, there is always an even number and a multiple of $3$ (they may be the same) in the set $\{n,n+1,n+2\}$. Hance, the product of these numbers is a multiple of $6$.

Comment: do u need do any algebraic working to prove this claim?

Answer (score 0):

We can show that $n(n+1)(n+2)$ is divisible by $2$ and by $3$. Since $2$ and $3$ are coprime, i.e. $\gcd(2,3)=1$, this implies that the product is divisible by $2\times 3 = 6$.

The positive integers $1,2,3,4,5,6,\ldots$, when divided by two, leave remainders $1,0,1,0,1,0,\ldots$ (They go odd, even, odd, even, etc.) For any three consecutive numbers the possible remainders are either $1,0,1$ or $0,1,0$. It follows that for any three consecutive numbers, at least one of them is divisible by $2$, i.e. leaves remainder $0$. It follows that the product must also be divisible by two.

The positive integers $1,2,3,4,5,6,\ldots$, when divided by three, leave remainders $1,2,0,1,2,0,\ldots$ For any three consecutive numbers the possible remainders are either $1,2,0$ or $2,0,1$ or $0,1,2$. It follows that for any three consecutive numbers, at least one of them is divisible by $3$, i.e. leaves remainder $0$. It follows that the product must also be divisible by three.

Since the product of any three consecutive numbers is divisible by *both* $2$ *and* $3$, and since $2$ and $3$ are coprime, it follows that the product of any three consecutive numbers is divisible by $2 \times 3 = 6$.